How can i specify a custom output folder in package.json when using vite to build a reactjs app?
I am trying to specify an out put folder when building my reactjs app in the package.json file .
the file is as follows:
"scripts": {
"dev": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
},
in order to build i just run npm run build , but i want the files/ dll's  for the client app to go to a custom folder .
How can i specify this in the file while still being able to run npm run build
I have tried
  "build": "vite build src --emptyOutDir",

but this gives an error
"Could not resolve entry module "src/index.html"
How can i do this ?

You can do this in your vite.config.js file.
In defineConfig(), add a property build like so:
  build: {
    outDir: “./my_custom_folder”,
  }


at the moment it is outDir: '../wwwroot',    so can i put 'd:\reacttest'

if i go back to wwwroot i cant see any dll's

I have tried it , doesnt seem to put all dll's in the folder

They seem to be going to C:\Dev\reactTestApp\bin\Debug\net7.0 ?

"so can i put 'd:\reacttest'" - I don't think it will accept an absolute path. Try using a relative path (relative to the root directory of your project). If the destination is outside the root of your project, you may need to set the emptyOutDir flag, which you can do in your vite.config.js build options:
  build: {
    outDir: “../my_custom_folder”,
    emptyOutDir: true
  }


so can i have    outDir: "d:/publish"   ?

I tried that and if i look in the folder not all dlls are there ?

even i fi use ../publish , not all files are there ?

Your question was how to specify a custom output folder for a vite react build. I believe I’ve answered that question and helped you get past the error you were receiving, "Could not resolve entry module "src/index.html". Typically your build output folder includes index.html, an assets folder with minified js and css files, and any static assets you have placed in the public folder of your project. If you are expecting to see other files in the build folder, that may be a different question outside the scope of this one.

You say to publish the .sln file. But in Visual Studio i go to the clientapp right click and publish ?

does Visual Studio generate a script that it runs to do this  that i can look at ?
